# Shortcut to finding first match in file

Tags: regex, vim

When searching with "/" in vim I find myself often wanting to go the first match of a file.

I know that I can simply do:

```
gg/<pattern>
```

but the "gg" adds an entry into my jump list which I may not want.

I feel there should be a way within the pattern to jump to the first match of the file.

Something like:

```
/<pattern>/<argument to specify first in file>
```

Does this functionality exist, or can anyone offer a mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid adding to the jump list, the `:keepjumps` command can be used, but you'll get a long command, because this now goes through an Ex command, and you need `:execute` for the concluding `<Enter>`:

```
:execute "keepjumps normal! gg/<pattern>/\<CR>"
```

An alternative is using a `:range`; the combination of `0` (goes to the top) and `/.../` (search), combined with `;` goes to the first *line* with a match:

```
:0;/<pattern>/
```

If you need to position the cursor on the exact first match (and it isn't at the beginning of the line), an additional `n` is needed:

```
:0;/<pattern>/normal! n
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I put a little function I wrote to make this easier to use in another answer...would appreciate any feedback...

Answer (score 2):

`/` and `?` start the search from the current cursor position and there's nothing you can do about it.

As an alternative, you could use:

```
:g/foo/#
```

or:

```
:il[ist] /foo
```

which are much better than `/` for *searching* anyway.

Comment: I tried :g/foo/# but it just took me to the number I put for #...if was searching for the first match of "foo" in the current buffer is this the correct form?: :g/foo/1

Comment: No. `#` is an actual `#`. Once you press `<CR>`, you get a list of all lines matching your pattern: type `:23<CR>` to go to line 23.

Comment: -Or- you can use '23G' (in normal mode) to go to line 23; i.e. 2 fewer key presses ( : <cr> )

Comment: @Cometsong, you forgot the `<CR>` that puts you back to normal mode: `<CR>23G` versus `:23<CR>`.

Comment: @romaini - my bad; I was thinking in general from normal mode, not backing out of the `cmd` mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking this because you want to find the declaration of a variable, then know that vim provides the `gD` normal command for that purpose.

For more information:

```
:help gd
:help gD
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ingo's answer I put this in my .vimrc:

```
function! GotoFirstMatch()
    call inputsave()
    let userInput = input('')
    execute "keepjumps normal! gg/".userInput."/\<CR>"
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>/f :call GotoFirstMatch()<CR>
```

I'm still fairly new to vimscript...would appreciate any feedback...

EDIT:

I've also started using this shortcut quite a bit:

```
[<C-i>
```

Which is like using the "*" command but having it go to the first match of the file rather than the next match after the cursor

Answer (score -1):

You can map `/` to `gg/`

```
:nnoremap / gg/
```

Comment: Two problems with this: 1. I don't _always_ want this behavior when I search. and 2. won't the "gg" in the mapping still add an entry to my jump list?

Comment: Although `gg` itself is just two keystrokes, you can do something like using a leader key to execute the mapping only when you precede it with leader key. I am not sure about the jump list question.